# Navigating ID properties to source with an OData API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a class which is exposed by an ASP.NET OData V4 API:

```
public class Person
{
    public int TitleId { get; set; }
    //Other properties like First Name, Last Name, DoB and so on...
}
```

The TitleId property is an Id that maps to a persons Title (Mr, Miss, Mrs so on) which is located at a different OData endpoint address.

Is there any way of providing metadata to let the consumer of the API know where the lookup values are for this property or should I approach this in a different way?

Edit: I am looking for a way to provide metadata to inform the consumer of the location of the lookup values. There is no database involved, this is a mapping layer over a much more complicated API.

Comment: Is there a `Title` entity? Is it part of the same service as `Person`?

Comment: Yes there is a Title entity. It is not on the Person service but it is available via the Lookup service. We have a number of lookup types - Title, Gender, Country etc. and I would like to inform the consumer of the API where the locations of these lookup types are. For example they are making an input form. They would need the core entity (Person) and the lookup types (Title) in this case amongst others so the consumer of the API can let their users select what the Title of the person is.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the Class of Title and have that in the Database this is working:

```
public class Title
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TitleName { get; set; }
}
```

then use this that as Virtual in your current model.

```
[ForeignKey("TitleId")]
public virtual Title { get; set; }

public int TitleId{ get; set; }
```

I'm sure it does the mapping.
then just address them to `Title.TitleName`.